# ASP.NET page inheritance: Controls from base class are not initialized

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, webforms

I am using a base page and an inherited page. The base page is working fine.

In the inherited page I have the following @Page-directive:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="SubPage" CodeFileBaseClass="BasePage" CodeFile="SubPage.aspx.cs" %>
```

and the following code-behind file

> public partial class SubPage: BasePage

The problem is that in Page_Load of the **base** class, all Controls are null.

A master-page is no solution for me in this case.

Comment: Unlike Winforms, page (form) inheritance is not "visual". Master pages are the "right" way to get a hierarchy or "layers" of controls. Base pages are generally used to hold common logic, not common UI.

Comment: But i want to override methods from the base class. That is not possible when using master pages

Comment: You can override methods that way, but you can't do controls that way.

Comment: Did you override the OnInit method and forget to call base.OnInit (which calls InitialComponent and sets up your controls)?

Comment: Please can you post some more code @user2224780 ?

Answer (score 1):

Inhert your code-behind as you would normally using:

```
public partial class SubPage: BasePage
```

and in markup do something like:

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="SubPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:

If masterpage is not what you want you'll have to do:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="BasePage" CodeFileBaseClass="BasePage" CodeFile="SubPage.aspx.cs" %>
```

and copy whole markup of BasePage below. Code-Behind is inherited same way again:

```
public partial class SubPage: BasePage
```